# Layout Issue: Two Fixed Columns in Center

Tags: css, layout

How can I position Label #2 and Label #3 in the center of the `panel` div given that Label #1 and Label #4 are floating left and right, respectively.

I would also like to move Label #2 and Label #3 below Label #1 and Label #4 when the browser width reaches a certain height. So Label #1 and Label #4 should be together, as should be Label #2 and Label #3 right below them.

See my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/p7ws5cxx

```css
html, body {
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#panel {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
.box-1, .box-2, .box-3, .box-4 {
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center-box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float :left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
.box-4 {
  float: right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) { 
  .box-1, .box-4 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  .center-box {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="panel"> 
    <span class="box-1">Label #1</span>
    <div class="center-box"> 
        <span class="box-2">Label #2</span>
        <span class="box-3">Label #3</span>
    </div> 
    <span class="box-4">Label #4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to reorder the elements within the markup?

Comment: @HashemQolami Yes I am trying that.

Comment: @kolor if you can draw 2 images 1.normal and 2.narrow to describe what you need it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that changing the order of HTML elements is allowed, the layout can be achieved by `float`ing the `.box-1`/`.box-4` to `left`/`right` and displaying the other boxes as inline elements.

Then in order to align them at the center of the panel, we can add `text-align: center` to the `.center-box` element.

Also note that in an inline flow, there's a [whitespace between inline-level elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements). One option to remove the gap is to set the `font-size` of parent to `0` and then re-set it to the default value on children.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    font: 500 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
#panel {
    background: #ddd;
}
#panel:after,
#panel:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.box-1, .box-2, .box-3, .box-4 {
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.box-1 {
    float: left;
}
.box-4 {
    float: right;
}
.box-2, .box-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.center-box {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) { 
    [class^="box-"] {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="panel"> 
    <span class="box-1">Label #1</span>
    <span class="box-4">Label #4</span>
    <div class="center-box"> 
        <span class="box-2">Label #2</span>
        <span class="box-3">Label #3</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you for your help.